# Possible usage of after (sec 0.)

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-core

Are there any situations when *after* function from Async library can be used with the time span of 0. seconds?

```
after (sec 0.)
```

Comment: Just curious, is this inspired by javascript's `setTimeout(_, 0)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `after` or `at` with times in the past will just return `Deferred.unit`. So it's safe, but there's not a lot of point.